How to handle identifier = identifier in ANTLR 4?
How to handle following input for ANTLR4 parser?

if (Weekly_navigation_volume < daily_navigation_volume ){
then do ur job
}

The grammar I tried:
grammar Rules;

program: statement+;

statement
    : ifStatement
    | thenStatement
    ;

ifStatement
    : 'if' condition block (elseIfStatement)* (elseStatement)?
    ;

elseIfStatement
    : 'else' 'if' condition block
    ;

elseStatement
    : 'else' block
    ;

thenStatement
    : 'then' action
    ;

condition
    : '(' expr ')'
    ;

block
    : '{' statement* '}'
    ;

expr
    : comparison
    | logicalExpression
    | expr 'AND' expr
    | expr 'OR' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

comparison
    : IDENTIFIER comparisonOperator (IDENTIFIER | VALUE | STRING)
    | IDENTIFIER '=' (IDENTIFIER | VALUE | STRING)
    ;

comparisonOperator
    : '>' | '<' | '==' | '!=' | '>=' | '<='
    ;

logicalExpression
    : comparison ('AND' | 'OR') comparison
    ;

action
    : ~('{' | '}' | 'if' | 'else' | '\n')+
    ;

IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_@#$%^&*()\-+=!~`\\|;:'",<.>/?]*;
VALUE: [0-9]+ ('%' | [0-9]*('.'[0-9]+)?); 
STRING: '"' ~'"'* '"' | '\'' ( ~'\'' )* '\'' ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

This is the result:

(program (statement (ifStatement if (condition ( (expr (comparison Weekly_navigation_volume (comparisonOperator >) subin))) <missing ')'>) (block { (statement (ifStatement if (condition ( (expr (comparison Weekly_navigation_volume (comparisonOperator >) 100)) )) (block { (statement (thenStatement then (action the customer will receive a 10% discount on their next data bundle purchase))) }))) }) (elseIfStatement else if (condition ( (expr (comparison Instant_og_idd_ibp_call_revenue (comparisonOperator >) 10)) )) (block { (statement (thenStatement then (action the customer will be rewarded with 50% free minutes for their next international call))) })))))

How to handle this:
identifier = value and string in double or single quote working

Please specify exactly what you mean by "how to handle something". It's not clear what you want to achieve.

@MikeLischke above grammer need dto support
if(Weekly_navigation_volume =daily_navigation_volume)
currently above grammer supports
if(Weekly_navigation_volume ="daily_navigation_volume")
or
if(Weekly_navigation_volume ='daily_navigation_volume')

i need one more thing like if(Weekly_navigation_volume =1 MB) @MikeLischke "1 MB " and '1 MB' is working

Why the 'then' keyword, inside the block statemant in your code? Does it shold be: 'f (Weekly_navigation_volume < daily_navigation_volume ) then {  do ur job }'
